# Can someone determine my location by watching the entry node

Tags: anonymity

I know My ISP will know my location based on the cell tower location I connect to. How about someone watching the entry Node. Can they determine my location. If so at what level. A country, state, city, GPS coordinates, cell tower I connect to, street address, one Mile squire area?

Comment: please clarify what you mean with "**watching** the entry node"?!?

Comment: maybe [this animation from the EFF](https://www.eff.org/pages/tor-and-https) helps you to understand a little bit more about who sees what with or without Tor...

Comment: Your ISP will know your location because is your ISP, you signed a contract right?! Who will know your location based on the cell tower location you connect to, are other people or anyone that can see your IP.

Answer (score 2):

When using a cellular data connection, you don't get an IP address for yourself. You are behind NAT. From the IP address, you could probably determine the country (+state?) and the carrier. The combination of IP, source port, and time would be enough to identify you if the adversary has the power to subpoena your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

Actually some extensions allow web/active content to access even your GPS data, so - basically, rather "yes" than "no", but it will be really difficult